# CSS HTML - Background Image pushing into the header

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a problem where the background image gets pushes into the header when the page is NOT tall enough to load the complete image in the body.

```
@media (min-width: 1350px)
.page-wrap {
    background-image: url('whitebg5.png'), url('leftbiger.png'), url('rightbiger2.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-y, no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-position: center top, left center, right center;
```

The home page looks like this:

[image: Expected result]

But the product page which isn't as tall looks like this:

[image: What I get]

Does anyone know some way that I could fix this?

I've tried using margins and paddings but the result was the header getting pushed down with the margin too. Background-size: container; did not seem to work either.

If someone knows a fix, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Could you please provide the HTML markup in question and all relevant styles? A jsfiddle would be even better if you could isolate the problem

Comment: its contain; not container;